# Is there a way to create a "header row" for a Winforms ComboBox?

Tags: winforms, combobox

Is there a way to create a "header row" for a winforms combo box?

So that's it's always displayed at the top?

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is: probably not.  You would have to make your own usercontrol to do something like that.

This [Getting ComboBox to show a TreeView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/03/03/384430.aspx) shows how to so something like that.  Just replace the treeview with a usercontrol that contains a label at the top and a listbox.  Pass your combobox list of items to the usercontrol, etc.

Comment: any ideas on how to approach it?